# Unable to install package Sleuth in R

Tags: r, namespaces, lazy-loading

I've been trying to install the Sleuth package in R all morning and it keeps giving me errors. This is how I tried to install it:

```
if(!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))  
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("DESeq2") 

BiocManager::install ("rhdf5")
install.packages("devtools") 
devtools:: install_github("pachterlab/sleuth")
```

I did use the library() command.

I get the following error messages:
Error: object 'h5write.default' is not exported by 'namespace:rhdf5'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'sleuth'

- removing 'C:/Users/31625/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/sleuth'

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found that there's current an open [issue](https://github.com/pachterlab/sleuth/issues/259) on Github discussing this problem.

Currently there is a workaround which was shared in the same issue on Github:

- Run `git clone https://github.com/pachterlab/sleuth`
- Remove the last line in ./sleuth/NAMESPACE which is the h5write.default that raises the error during installation - ignore the warning in the first line
- Then in R: `devtools::install('./sleuth/')`

It worked for me while using Linux - ZorinOS and R 4.1.2 but it should work on Windows as well.

Someone also opened a PR to fix the whole issue but it ***seems*** they are not updating the package anymore (unfortunately).